# Cross-browser Access html content of object tag

Tags: javascript, html, cross-browser, object-tag

I have `object` tag with a data attribute to a html file from same domain.

I want to access the content of the html.

HTML:

```
<object id="object" width="420" height="360" data="jsp/index.html"></object>
```

JS:

```
var object = document.getElementById("object").contentDocument;
var html = object.getElementById("tmpl").innerHTML
```

The above code is working in all browsers except `IE7`

Please help me in accessing the DOM content of `object` tag in IE7

Comment: Instead of using contentDocument, try using contentWindow . This might work, i think it has support for IE. Kindly do tell me whether it works for you .

Comment: No i tried using that too.. No luck :(

Comment: Are you sure that your code work in general? Neither in my Chrome , Safari browser, IE8 (IE8 and Document (standard) mode) did your example work. Chrome and Safari accept the first line, but not the second line. The result of innerHTML is 'null'.

Comment: http://jsperf.com/objectvsiframevsdiv
check it here. its working fine in all browsers except `IE7`

Comment: what about to place it into `div` and try to access?

Answer (score 2):

Ok so i tried to play around the code a little as provided by you and i found out  some important things, first of which is:

1> I first tried to get the contents of html like this in firebug :

```
console.log(document.getElementById("iframe").contentDocument.innerHTML);
```

I am gonna attach my firebug result here :

[image]

So you can see that there is a permission denied coming up here.

2> Similarly, i tried out for object also and this is what i got :

[image]

From here it is fairly evident that it is failing because of the **[Same Origin Policy](http://thinkfree-thinkfree.blogspot.com/2013/01/problems-due-to-same-origin-policy.html)**.

I  do not know how you are accessing them, but for me this domain and host in not accessible. This is guess, is also the reason for you failing to get the contents of the object id . I suggest that you use  **[Cross-site HTTP requests or the CORS way](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)** to get things done here .