# Find a particular tag in a div for which there is no id

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I am using jquery and trying to find a `<html>` tag that is embedded in `<object>` . I am trying to use find method, but not able to find one. Can someone please guide.

Code:

```
if (dialogObject.find('head')) {
                        var findelemnt = $('#dialogObject').find('html');
                        var testthis = findelemnt.attr("class");
                        alert(testthis);
                    }
                    else { alert("not found") }
```

dialoObject is a `<div>` . Attaching a screen shot of page.

[image]

Comment: We need to see more code to help you. Can you create a jsfiddle? With the code you've provided we can't, for instance, tell how dialDiv or dialogObject were defined and what they contain.

Comment: Just wondering, why are you using an `<object>` tag rather than an iframe? BTW I don't think `<object>` tags work in IE.

Comment: @MattBrowne : `<object>` works in IE. at least for this code it is working. And if I use <iFrames> then would I not be facing this problem?

Comment: @MattBrowne : Have changed my code to `<iFrames>` , but that didnt help.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is probably failing due to the [same origin policy](http://thinkfree-thinkfree.blogspot.com/2013/01/problems-due-to-same-origin-policy.html). See https://stackoverflow.com/a/14453363/560114.

Try it with a local URL - I'm guessing you can get it to work there by using this code:

```
$('#dialogObject')[0].contentDocument
```

Comment: I am getting objectHTMLdocument in alert. Code:       
var findelemnt = $('#dialogObject')[0].contentDocument;

Comment: Interesting. I've just discovered that for e.g. `<object id="myId" name="myName" ...></object>`, `window.myId.contentDocument` === `window.myName.document`.

Comment: Either way, I don't think you'll be able to access its contents if it's a remote URL like jquery.com.

Answer (score 0):

$('#dialogObject').find('head') - you have call your element by the right selector.

Comment: OP might be doing that already. For all we know, `var dialogObject = $('#dialogObject')`. Besides, it shouldn't matter since we're using `find()` anyway, as opposed to say `children()` or `filter()`.

Comment: @enenalan : I have edited my code. I am still getting undefined int alert; whereas there is a class attribute for <html> tag.

Comment: @Wynand : no help. Getting undefined in alert box.

Answer (score 0):

Provided that you're attempting to embed *nested* browsing context, you could add a "name" attribute:

```
<object id="dialogObject" data="http://domain/path" name="myWindow"></object>
```

and access the nested `<html>` element using `myWindow.document.documentElement` or `window["myWindow"].document.documentElement`.

EDIT 1: Although you have access to the `<object>` element by means of its "id" attribute, e.g. `window.dialogObject`, `window["dialogObject"]` or of course `document.getElementById("dialogObject")`, you can access the *nested* `window` object by means of its "name" attribute, e.g. `myWindow` or `window["myWindow"]`.

To that effect, `$(myWindow.document.documentElement)` is equivalent to using `$(myWindow.document).find('html')`.

EDIT 2: If you do prefer to use the "id" attribute as per your original code, you can combine [Matt Browne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/560114/matt-browne)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25130394/192886) with the above to achieve the following:

```
$($('#dialogObject')[0].contentDocument).find('html')
```

although I would suggest the following instead:

```
$(document.getElementById("dialogObject").contentDocument.documentElement)
```

Apart from that, don't forget to execute your code within a document ready event handler to make sure that the DOM has fully loaded by the time you try to access any element in question.

Comment: @Waynand: could you please elaborate a bit. How to access the html element using myObject?

Comment: I think he may have meant `document.myObject`, which if I recall correctly should give you the element whose `name` is "myObject".

Comment: I am able to access the object. Since I have Id for that. The content embedded inside it is what that I am not able to access..

Comment: Good point...so an equivalent to @Wynand's answer would be `$('#dialogObject')[0].document.documentElement`...not sure if that will actually work though.

Comment: @MattBrowne : Have put that in alert and alert doesnt even return any popup.

Comment: @Wynand : Here is what I am doing:
var findelemnt = $(window.myObject.document).find('html')[0];
                        alert(findelemnt);
                        var testthis = findelemnt.attr("class");

I am getting alert window but no class alert. Whereas there is a class attribute

Comment: @Wynand : have added the code block to your code above. Please check and guide

Comment: Remember that with `[0]` we're accessing the actual HTML element (same as `.get(0)`) and not the jQuery object that wraps the first matched element, so you could try removing the `[0]` and leave everything else as is, or using `var testthis = findelemnt.getAttribute("class")` or alternatively `var testthis = findelemnt.className`.