# How to get path id of SVG image using AngularJS

Tags: jquery, angularjs, svg

I am trying to find path id of a SVG image using AngularJS and Jquery but below code is not working. Any suggestion?

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller('uiCtrl', function($scope,$http) {
 $scope.list1 = {img : 'https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/gallardo.svg'};

});


  document.querySelector('object').addEventListener('load',function(){
        var p = this.contentDocument.documentElement.querySelectorAll('path');
        for(i=0;i<p.length;i++){
         p[i].addEventListener('click', function(){ 
              alert("PATH ID"+this.id+"…")
            });
        }
    });
```

```css
#previewImg{
border : 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="uiCtrl" >
<object id="previewImg" ng-attr-data="{{list1.img}}" type="image/svg+xml" width=100% height="100%"></object>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you trying to get SVG path via jQuery click function ?

Comment: Yes path id but data src is from angularjs. So there is confilct with jquery.

Comment: path is in the object tag's document, you'll need to get that document and then search for the path using that. var otherDocument = document.getElementById("previewImg").contentDocument;

Comment: Ok I have updated my question added `.contentDocument`

Comment: trying this? http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/41168/

Comment: Thanks but I want to get path id of SVG on click over it not image src.

Comment: You need to host the image on your site. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14435793/cross-browser-access-html-content-of-object-tag

Comment: Still getting error on localhost :                                              VM1114:66 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLObjectElement': Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost:8080" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
    at HTMLObjectElement.contentDocumentDesc.get [as contentDocument] (<anonymous>:66:14)
    at HTMLObjectElement.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/admin/:1186:22)

Comment: Above was due to spring security. Now I disabled the same and its working. Thanks for your suggestion @RobertLongson